# how open 80 port on Ubuntu 16 (for hosting timeweb)

Tags: ubuntu, port, hosting, vds

How to open port 80 on ubuntu vds hosting for my web site. using iptables is not running, like writing that is open, and when I check via telnet 188.225.87.209 80 displays: telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: 1. On your server make sure you have a process listening to port 80
2. Make sure your routers are forwarding ports properly + not blocking them

Comment: @nzjun90 Sorry, do not tell me how to test it? I'm very beginner user)

Comment: use `netstat -tuplen` command to check if a process is listening to port 80. Since you are doing hosting, you usually ask the hosting company to unblock port but by default, port 80 is usually unblocked. I did a quick check on the ip/port you provided and I seem to be able to access it from my end. Has the problem been resolved?

Comment: @nzjun90 Yes! Thank you very much